# How to correctly implement where for jsonb array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I added the jsonb field in which I want to store the ID.

Next, I need to implement a "search" of records by the contents of this field.

Everywhere, including the documentation ([link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html)), I saw this operator - `@>`. But I didn't manage to use it:

```rb
User.where.not("migration_ids @> ?", 1)
```

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb @> integer)
LINE 1: ...s".* FROM "users" WHERE NOT (migration_ids @> 1) LIMI...
                                                      ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Tell me, please, how to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work
`User.where.not("migration_ids @> ?", "1")`